# Unable to identify image in java using sikuli

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sikuli

I am trying to automate a web application using selenium webdriver (Eclipse IDE), selenium was not able to identify a particular element (even though it had Xpath) so I tried to integrate sikuli with Java Eclipse.
I recorded the click in Sikuli and saved the script took that image into Java code and tried but it was throwing an error:
FindFailed: can not find Pattern("C:\1424416444710.png").similar(0.7) on the screen.

Below is the code I used in Eclipse:

```
  try  
       { Screen s = new Screen();  
         System.out.println("Trying to find the image");  
         Pattern image = new Pattern("C:\\1424416444710.png");  
         s.wait(image, 10);  
         s.click(image);  
       }
    catch (Exception e)  
       {  
         e.printStackTrace();  
       }
```

Comment: Adding on... While running the script through Sikuli IDE am able to see the required click is happening.

Comment: It is people-who-don't-know-how-to-use-debug invasion on SO

Comment: Go back to selenium, and post a question with your code & html document if you're stuck. That'll be a lot easier to help with. Or add your image & html to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I ran Sikuli IDE again and captured the image and passed that to Java code, now Eclipse is able to recognize the image.